# Tick labels displaying outside axis limits

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to automatically not display tick mark labels if they would protrude past the axis itself? For example, consider the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylab as P, numpy as N, math as M
xvals=N.arange(-10,10,0.1)
yvals=[ M.sin(x) for x in xvals ]
P.plot( xvals, yvals )
P.show()
```

See how the -10 and 10 labels on the x-axis poke out to the left and right of the plot? And similar for the -1.0 and 1.0 labels on the y-axis. Can I automatically suppress plotting these but retain the ones that do not go outside the plot limits?

Comment: the font of the xaxis ticks can be changed manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just format the axis ticks yourself and then prune the ones
that are hanging over. The recommended way to deal with setting up the axis is
to use the [ticker API](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html). So for example

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xvals=np.arange(-10,10,0.1)
yvals=[ np.sin(x) for x in xvals ]
ax.plot( xvals, yvals )

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='both'))
plt.show()
```

Here we are creating a figure and axes, plotting the data, and then setting the xaxis
major ticks. The formatter `MaxNLocator` is given the 
argument `prune='both'` which is described in the docs [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator).

This is not exactly what you were asking for, but maybe it will solve your problem.